# Floating and fading text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had an idea. I wonder if it's possible to achieve with jQuery/CSS3 one effect: click on element would made appear new text on element/cursor position. This text will be slowly sliding up and fading out. Button/element doesn't change.

It might be little bit difficult to describe it in text so I put it inside picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK2Lh.png

It is quite usual effect in computer games when you buy something but I don't remember I've ever seen it on website.

Please, do you know how is it called and where I can find some solution? Or can you give me clues to achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: I think it is achievable.  When a mouse event occurs, we are given its x,y coordinates on the screen.  We will also know that the event occurred.  To achieve the visual, we would likely use CSS fixed positioning  ... see http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Comment: Changed my answer so that it appends text on click for you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Changed answer after asker explained it better**

I see what you want now. Here is an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d4qGc/667/
It appends the text and then applies an animation using css opacity and top positioning to the appended text afterwards.

HTML:

```
<p><br><br><br></p> <!-- pushing button down a bit -->
<div id="Content">
    <button id="Add">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
  $('#Add').on('click', function () {
    $('<p id="message">+$59.99!</p>').appendTo('#Content');
  });
}); 

$("#Add").click(function() {
$("#message").animate({
    top: -100,
    opacity: 0 
}, 1000,"linear",
    function() {
$(this).remove();
})
});
```

CSS:

```
#message { position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks similar what I wanted to and I believe this will be some part of it. But I meant something slightly different. I updated image in original post, I hope it will be more clear. ;)

Comment: Oh, perfect! Many thanks, edited version is exactly what I wish. You are my hero. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this(You will need JQuery):

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){

var elem = document.createElement("h3");
elem.style.position = "fixed";
elem.style.top = $("#buttonID").style("top") + 10;
elem.style.left = $("#buttonID").style("left") + 10;
elem.value = "" //Whatever value you want.
elem.id = "txtFloat";
document.getElementById("CONTAINER").appendChild(elem); //whatever container you want.


$("#txtFloat").animate({top:40px;},1500); //This will move the button up(The button needs to have position:fixed, or position:absolute for this to work).
$("#txtFloat").fadeOut(900); //This will fade the button as it is being moved up. The button will be faded out before it reaches the top of the animation.

});
```

---

## Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry, I probably explained it bad. :) I don't want to move button itself, I want to create new text (i.e. from data-whatever of element) which will be shown only for a few seconds over the button... in some elegant and fast way, I wonder if any jQuery plug-in exists. There are plug-ins for nearly everything. :)